# make a column in jqxgrid uneditable

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid, jqwidget

I have a jqxgrid for which I need to make first column uneditable. I tried the code mentioned in jqwidgets forum but that did not work.

```
> $("#jqxgrid").on('cellbeginedit', function (event)  {
>     var args = event.args;
>     console.log(args);
>     console.log("cell edit begins");  });
```

Here is the fiddle : [jqx-cell-unedit](http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/0u7n0ymg/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each column has "editable" property. To make it not-editable, set it to false.